# Enum Extension method call by Enum Name?

Tags: c#, enums

I have following code which is working fine . but i need to use extension method with its Enum type.

```
public class Dropdown
    {
        public Dropdown() { }
        public Dropdown(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
        public Dropdown(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StringId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public enum AccidentTypeEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "Minor")]
    Minor = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Major")]
    Major = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Severe")]
    Severe = 2
}
```

Extension Method

```
public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static List<Dropdown> ConvertToDropdown(this Enum mEnum)
        {
            var dropDownlist = new List<Dropdown>();

            var enumType = mEnum.GetType();

            var enumValuies = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
            foreach (var singleValue in enumValuies)
            {
                dropDownlist.Add(new Dropdown { Id = (int)singleValue, Name = singleValue.ToString() });

            }

            return dropDownlist;
       }
    }
```

**Question:**

Above code is working fine if i call extension method using  below lines

```
var TestAcident = AccidentTypeEnum.Major;
var resultDropdown = TestAcident.ConvertToDropdown();
```

But how can i call it just like below lines

```
 var resultDropdown = AccidentTypeEnum.ConvertToDropdown(); //<-- i need to use like this. but it not working
```

Comment: You can't, at the moment. You're basically wanting extension methods on the type rather than on an instance, and that's not currently available in C#. There's a possibility that it'll happen at some point, but not just yet :(

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks .i'm using it on instance  :(

Comment: No you're not - `AccidentTypeEnum.ConvertToDropdown()` is trying to call the method *on the type name*.

Comment: `var TestAcident = AccidentTypeEnum.Major;
var resultDropdown = TestAcident.ConvertToDropdown();` using this one right now

Comment: Yes, and that should be fine. You've asked whether you can use `AccidentTypeEnum.ConvertToDropdown()` and I'm saying you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
List<AccidentTypeEnum> types = Utils<AccidentTypeEnum>.ConvertToDropdown();
```

this way:

```
/// <summary>Pseudo extension class for enumerations</summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">Enumeration type</typeparam>
public class Utils<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public static List<Dropdown> ConvertToDropdown()
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);

        return enumType.IsEnum
            ? enumType.GetEnumValues()
                .OfType<TEnum>()
                .Select(e => new Dropdown
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(enumType, e.ToString()) as Enum),
                    Name = GetDisplay(e)
                })
                .ToList()
            : throw new ArgumentException($"{enumType.Name} is not enum");
    }

    private static string GetDisplay<T>(T value)
    {
        var enumValueText = value.ToString();

        var displayAttribute = value
            .GetType()
            .GetField(enumValueText)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
            .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return displayAttribute == null ? enumValueText : displayAttribute.Description;
    }
}
```